# Delete personal account, keep business account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A while back, I set up a page for myself, similar to, say, how many public figures have a page. I'm no Madonna, but, who is?

However, I still have my personal Facebook account, and the associated activity. Like, I've got friends, am in groups, I'm an admin on a bunch of pages, including of some clients, run the occasional ad campaign, etc.

I would like my public-facing presence to be my page, not my personal profile. I'm totally fine to not have any public activity (as part of a personal profile), but not being able to administer pages, and perhaps groups, is a bit more problematic.

What is the best approach for this? What is any approach for this?

I'm aware of the presumed existence of a profile-to-page migration tool ([Facebook FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/116067818477568?helpref=faq_content)), but that Facebook tool does not appear to work ([link to tool in Facebook FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/migrate)).

[This](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31333/how-can-i-manage-the-transition-from-personal-account-to-professional-page) ancient SE post links to a Facebook FAQ that links to the same non-existing migration tool. In the post, the accepted answer gives a bunch of interesting tips, but no clear action that needs to be taken.